# How to create a directory in Scripter Automation

Tags: vbscript, plugins, directory

Is it possible to create a directory in Scripter Automation?

I need to call ActiveX plugin. In VB you can call it with

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:\Documents and Settings\AllUsers
\Documents\NewDirectory")
```

Comment: There does not seem to be a GIS component to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `md $path -Force`, per this resource [Weekend Scripter: Use PowerShell to Create Folder](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/03/08/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-create-folder/)

Comment: I solved it by creating a FSO